# How do you edit a unit's nickname?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

In the Customize screen the "nickname" editing button is disabled for me. How do I make it become active?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A soldier must rank up before they are allowed to have a nickname.  They'll be auto-assigned one at Sergeant rank, and after that point you can change it as you see fit.

[image]